# Q: Need to add a list but not sure were in the code

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, code

I have a Visualforce page. When you selected a product. I need the "OpportunityLineItem.ListPrice" and "OpportunityLineItem.Terms_c" fields to show the value. The only way I can get the system to show a value is to save the opp. I need to be able to see the values before saving. I am think the problem is with this part of the apex class

```
for(PricebookEntry d : AvailableProducts){
if((String)d.Id==toSelect){
shoppingCart.add(new opportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=theOpp.Id,
PriceBookEntry=d, PriceBookEntryId=d.Id, UnitPrice=d.UnitPrice ));
            break;
```

**When I add List price to the code I get a error
Compile Error: Field is not writeable: OpportunityLineItem.ListPrice at line 137 column 157"**

```
shoppingCart.add(new opportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=theOpp.Id
PriceBookEntry=d, PriceBookEntryId=d.Id, UnitPrice=d.UnitPrice,
listprice=d.unitprice));
```

I think I need a list to hold the values or something like this

```
List<Id,String> listPriceList = new List<Id,String>(); 
listPriceList.add(OpportunityLineItem.Id , OpportunityLineItem.ListPrice);
```

But I can't seem to get it to work I all ways get a error.
 **"list must have exactly 1 type argument at line 24 column 9"**

Any help would be great.

Here is all of the code

```
public with sharing class opportunityProductEntryExtensionTest {

public Opportunity theOpp {get;set;}
public String searchString {get;set;}
public opportunityLineItem[] shoppingCart {get;set;}
public priceBookEntry[] AvailableProducts {get;set;}
public Pricebook2 theBook {get;set;}   

public String toSelect {get; set;}
public String toUnselect {get; set;}
public Decimal Total {get;set;}

public Boolean overLimit {get;set;}
public Boolean multipleCurrencies {get; set;}

private Boolean forcePricebookSelection = false;

private opportunityLineItem[] forDeletion = new opportunityLineItem[]{};


public opportunityProductEntryExtensionTest(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    // Need to know if org has multiple currencies enabled
    multipleCurrencies = UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization();

    // Get information about the Opportunity being worked on
    if(multipleCurrencies)
        theOpp = database.query('select Id, Pricebook2Id, Pricebook2.Name, CurrencyIsoCode from Opportunity where Id = \'' + controller.getRecord().Id + '\' limit 1');
    else
        theOpp = [select Id, Pricebook2Id, PriceBook2.Name from Opportunity where Id = :controller.getRecord().Id limit 1];

    // If products were previously selected need to put them in the "selected products" section to start with
    shoppingCart = [select Id, opportunityLineItem.listprice, Quantity, Terms_Length__c, TotalPrice, PriceBookEntry.unitprice, Product_Type__c, Terms__c, UnitPrice, Description, PriceBookEntryId, PriceBookEntry.Name,PriceBookEntry.IsActive, PriceBookEntry.Product2Id,PriceBookEntry.Product2.Name, PriceBookEntry.PriceBook2Id from opportunityLineItem where OpportunityId=:theOpp.Id];

    // Check if Opp has a pricebook associated yet
    if(theOpp.Pricebook2Id == null){
        Pricebook2[] activepbs = [select Id, Name from Pricebook2 where isActive = true limit 2];
        if(activepbs.size() == 2){
            forcePricebookSelection = true;
            theBook = new Pricebook2();
        }
        else{
            theBook = activepbs[0];
        }
    }
    else{
        theBook = theOpp.Pricebook2;
    }

    if(!forcePricebookSelection)
        updateAvailableList();}

// this is the 'action' method on the page
public PageReference priceBookCheck(){

    // if the user needs to select a pricebook before we proceed we send them to standard pricebook selection screen
    if(forcePricebookSelection){        
        return changePricebook();
    }
    else{

        //if there is only one active pricebook we go with it and save the opp
        if(theOpp.pricebook2Id != theBook.Id){
            try{
                theOpp.Pricebook2Id = theBook.Id;
                update(theOpp);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public String getChosenCurrency(){

    if(multipleCurrencies)
        return (String)theOpp.get('CurrencyIsoCode');
    else
        return '';
}

public void updateAvailableList() {

    // We dynamically build a query string and exclude items already in the shopping cart
    String qString = 'select Id, Pricebook2Id, IsActive, opportunityLineItem.listprice Product2.Name, Product2.Family, Product2.IsActive, Product2.Description, UnitPrice,Product2.Product_Type__c,Product2.Terms__c from PricebookEntry where IsActive=true and Pricebook2Id = \'' + theBook.Id + '\'';
    if(multipleCurrencies)
        qstring += ' and CurrencyIsoCode = \'' + theOpp.get('currencyIsoCode') + '\'';

    // note that we are looking for the search string entered by the user in the name OR description
    // modify this to search other fields if desired
    if(searchString!=null){
        qString+= ' and (Product2.Name like \'%' + searchString + '%\' or Product2.Description like \'%' + searchString + '%\')';
    }

    Set<Id> selectedEntries = new Set<Id>();
    for(opportunityLineItem d:shoppingCart){
        selectedEntries.add(d.PricebookEntryId);
    }

    if(selectedEntries.size()>0){
        String tempFilter = ' and Id not in (';
        for(Id i : selectedEntries){
            tempFilter+= '\'' + (String)i + '\',';
        }
        String extraFilter = tempFilter.substring(0,tempFilter.length()-1);
        extraFilter+= ')';

        qString+= extraFilter;
    }

    qString+= ' order by Product2.Name';
    qString+= ' limit 101';

    system.debug('qString:' +qString);        
    AvailableProducts = database.query(qString);

    // We only display up to 100 results... if there are more than we let the user know (see vf page)
    if(AvailableProducts.size()==101){
        AvailableProducts.remove(100);
        overLimit = true;
    }
    else{
        overLimit=false;
    }
}

public void addToShoppingCart(){

    // This function runs when a user hits "select" button next to a product

    for(PricebookEntry d : AvailableProducts){
        if((String)d.Id==toSelect){
            shoppingCart.add(new opportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=theOpp.Id, PriceBookEntry=d, PriceBookEntryId=d.Id, UnitPrice=d.UnitPrice ));
            break;
        }

    }

    updateAvailableList();  
}public PageReference removeFromShoppingCart(){

    // This function runs when a user hits "remove" on an item in the "Selected Products" section

    Integer count = 0;

    for(opportunityLineItem d : shoppingCart){
        if((String)d.PriceBookEntryId==toUnselect){

            if(d.Id!=null)
                forDeletion.add(d);

            shoppingCart.remove(count);
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }

    updateAvailableList();

    return null;
}

public PageReference onSave(){

    // If previously selected products are now removed, we need to delete them
    if(forDeletion.size()>0)
        delete(forDeletion);

    // Previously selected products may have new quantities and amounts, and we may have new products listed, so we use upsert here
    try{
        if(shoppingCart.size()>0)
            upsert(shoppingCart);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
    }  

    // After save return the user to the Opportunity
    return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
}

public PageReference onCancel(){

    // If user hits cancel we commit no changes and return them to the Opportunity   
    return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
}

public PageReference changePricebook(){

    // This simply returns a PageReference to the standard Pricebook selection screen
    // Note that is uses retURL parameter to make sure the user is sent back after they choose

    PageReference ref = new PageReference('/oppitm/choosepricebook.jsp');
    ref.getParameters().put('id',theOpp.Id);
    ref.getParameters().put('retURL','/apex/opportunityProductEntry?id=' + theOpp.Id);

    return ref;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListPrice is not available until you save the record. You would need to query the PricebookEntry.Product2Id and then query the for the standard pricebook price of the product. That would be the data to display.

You can do something like:

```
public Map<Id, Double> listPriceMap {get; private set;}  

List<PricebookEntry> pricebookEntries = new List<PricebookEntry>([select Id, ProductId, UnitPrice from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2.IsStandard = true and ProductId in :productIds]);
listPriceMap = new Map<Id, Double>(); 
for (PricebookEntry pbe : pricebookEntries) {  
    listPriceMap.put(pbe.ProductId, pbe.UnitPrice);
}
```

Then in your visualforce page:

```
  {!listPriceMap[opportunityLine.PricebookEntry.ProductId]}
```

Comment: I am trying the code out at the top of the apex class and I am getting a error. "Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'and' at line 5 column 146" I am not having very good luck getting it to work. Is the problem the place I am adding the new code?

Comment: My query had an error, it should be IsStandard = true. I edited the code. Also you will need to get the ProductIds from your line items in total. You will need to keep updating the map as you are adding new items to the shopping cart.